# Definition of OSCOMPSTAT values

Tags: control-m, return-code

I've tried to find a table with the definition for each COMPSTAT (related to the tool Control-M workload Automation) return code but without any success.
Can anyone tell me if such a table exists?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's the return code from whatever task was being executed at that time. By convention, a zero value means 'OK', and anything non-zero means an error of some kind.

Different utilities (i.e. external commands) have different possible return codes, so if the command were SCP then you would look up the code in the SCP documentation, and find that for example, '67' meant 'key exchange failed'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no table that contains the definition of each COMPSTAT return code.

OSCOMPSTAT stand for Control-M Operating System Completion Status. 
The value of COMPSTAT is set by the exit code of the command that was called.

Example:

- After calling the command [cat file1.txt] the value of COMPSTAT will be:

  - 0 if the file "file1.txt" is found
  - 1 if the file "file1.txt" is not found
- After calling the command [ctmfw] the value of COMPSTAT will be:

  - 0 if the specified file is found
  - 7 if the specified file is not found